# Writing left join in linq query with 5 table

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to Linq query. I want to get the List by doing Left Join. Is it possible to get all data in one linq query.

```
public class Center {
    public int centerId,
    public int customerId,
    public List<Note> notes
}

public class Note {
    public int noteId,
    public int centerId,
    public Instruction instruction
}

public class Instruction {
    public int instructionId,
    public int noteId,
    public int instructionText
}
```

I tried to write linq query but I am not getting the data in required format. My query is

```
var result = (from center in ctx.Center 
    join note in ctx.Note on center.centerId equals note.centerId into joinednote 

    from notes in joinednote.DefaultIfEmpty() 
    join inst in ctx.Instruction on notes.noteID equals args.noteID into joinedinst 

    from instruction in joinedarg.DefaultIfEmpty() 
    select new { center, notes, instruction }
).AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

Comment: If your question is just _Is it possible_, then the answer is yes

Comment: @Sunil I tried to write linq query but I am not getting the data in required format. My query is                                                                                           
(from center in ctx.Center 
join note in ctx.Note
on center.centerId equals note.centerId into joinednote
from notes in joinednote.DefaultIfEmpty()
join inst in ctx.Instruction 
on notes.noteID equals args.noteID into joinedinst
from instruction in joinedarg.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { center, notes, instruction }).AsEnumerable().ToList()

Comment: You should add your query into the question itself, it would be more visible and easier to help.

Comment: Can you add it to your question? Also, what is the expected output?

Comment: @Sunil I need the List of Center which contains List of Notes and each notes contains Instruction

Comment: why are you joining? If you have an instance of `Center`, you already have its list of `Notes` inside, and each `Note` has its `Instructions`?

Comment: I haven't used foreign keys in tables and I don't want to edit my table. So I am using the query to get data in desired format.

Comment: bad design leads to bad code - why not edit tables? and you won't get the output as the described classes because your projection is `select new { center, notes, instruction }`... you need to project a new `Center` and in it's list project the notes etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad design leads to bad code. You are going to do lots of work to get trivial things with a proper design. I strongly recommend that you add the foreign keys and if in Entity Framework properly set Navigation Properties.

As for the query itself in order to get the desired hierarchy of objects and not a flat collection like you got then:

```
var result = (from center in ctx.Center
              select new Center {
                  centerId = center.centerId,
                  customerId = center.customerId,
                  notes = ctx.Note.Where(n => n.centerId == center.centerId)
                                  .Select(n => new Note {
                                      noteId = n.noteId,
                                      centerId = n.centerId,
                                      instruction = ctx.Instruction.FirstOrDedault(i => i.noteId == n.noteId)
                                  })
              });
```

Another option is to use the query you wrote and then group all items by the `center`, and then inner group by the `note`s.

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed. Actually DB is already in production so I can't change schema now. Thats why I had to choose this approach. One more que - Will this query results a single SQL query or multiple SQL query..??

Comment: @artista_14 - I'd say check it and see :) Best approach for knowing is trying and learning.
As for DB being in production - don't know your business restrictions but I'd suggest for a version to correct database..